# How to Add a Value to an Array on Button Press (Having Trouble)

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I'm setting up a multipage form and have the steps assigned to an array.

What I am trying to figure out is the best way to add a new page to the form on button press. My solution was to build the new pages of the form (there will be 20 duplicates though, each with own variables).

Then I have a button labeled 'Add New' which calls a function to add a new line to the array, thus enabling the next page.

Of course, ideally my first solution was to have react automatically build a new page and variables but I'm not sure if that's feasible for me to do.

**steps.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { StepOne } from './StepOne'
import { StepTwo } from './StepTwo'
import { StepThree } from './StepThree'



const steps = 
    [
      {name: 'Job', component: <StepOne/>},
      {name: 'device 1', component: <StepTwo/>},

    ]

export { steps }
```

**home.js (where my form lives)**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import MultiStep from 'react-multistep'
import { steps } from './steps'
import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import newdevice from "./new-device";


class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <h1>Start a New Job</h1>

        <div className='container'>
    <div>
      <MultiStep steps={steps} />
    </div>
    <div className='container app-footer'>
      <h6>Press 'Enter' or click on progress bar for next step.</h6>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>

    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

**StepTwo.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { steps } from './steps'
import { StepThree } from './StepThree'
import update from 'react-addons-update';


export class StepTwo extends React.Component {

    addNew() {
      this.setState(previousState => ({
        steps: [...previousState.steps, "{name: 'device 2', component: <StepThree/>},"]
      }));
  }
        <div className='row'> 
        <div className="col-md-4">
        <button  onClick={this.addNew} variant="primary">Add a New Device</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**If you want to see the entire page of the form for a better idea, full StepTwo.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { steps } from './steps'
import { StepThree } from './StepThree'
import update from 'react-addons-update'; // ES6
// 


export class StepTwo extends React.Component {

    addNew() {
      this.setState(previousState => ({
        steps: [...previousState.steps, "{name: 'device 2', component: <StepThree/>},"]
      }));
  }



  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = { 
      Box: '', 
      VIN: '',
      Lbl: '',
      Year: '',
      Make: '',
      Model: '',
      Plate: '',
      ODO: '',
      Notes: '',
    }
    this.handleBoxChanged = this.handleBoxChanged.bind(this);
    this.handleVINChanged = this.handleVINChanged.bind(this);
    this.handleLblChanged = this.handleLblChanged.bind(this);
    this.handleYearhanged = this.handleYearChanged.bind(this);
    this.handleMakeChanged = this.handleMakeChanged.bind(this);
    this.handleModelChanged = this.handleModelChanged.bind(this);
    this.handlePlateChanged = this.handlePlateChanged.bind(this);
    this.handleODOChanged = this.handleODOChanged.bind(this);
    this.handleNotesChanged = this.handleNotesChanged.bind(this);
  }

  handleBoxChanged (event) {
    this.setState({Box: event.target.value})
  }
  handleVINChanged (event) {
    this.setState({VIN: event.target.value})
  }

  handleLblChanged (event) {
    this.setState({Lbl: event.target.value})
  }

  handleYearChanged (event) {
    this.setState({Year: event.target.value})
  }

  handleMakeChanged (event) {
    this.setState({Make: event.target.value})
  }

  handleModelChanged (event) {
    this.setState({Model: event.target.value})
  }

  handlePlateChanged (event) {
    this.setState({Plate: event.target.value})
  }

  handleODOChanged (event) {
    this.setState({ODO: event.target.value})
  }

  handleNotesChanged (event) {
    this.setState({Notes: event.target.value})
  }


  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='six columns'>
            <label>Device #</label>
            <input
              className='u-full-width'
              placeholder='Device #'
              type='text'
              onChange={this.handleBoxChanged}
              value={this.state.Box}
              autoFocus
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='six columns'>
            <label>VIN</label>
            <input
              className='u-full-width'
              placeholder='VIN'
              type='text'
              onChange={this.handleVINChanged}
              value={this.state.VIN}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='six columns'>
            <label>Label</label>
            <input
              className='u-full-width'
              placeholder='Label'
              type='text'
              onChange={this.handleLblChanged}
              value={this.state.Lbl}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='six columns'>
            <label>Year</label>
            <input
              className='u-full-width'
              placeholder='Year'
              type='text'
              onChange={this.handleYearChanged}
              value={this.state.Year}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='six columns'>
            <label>Make</label>
            <input
              className='u-full-width'
              placeholder='Make'
              type='text'
              onChange={this.handleMakeChanged}
              value={this.state.Make}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='six columns'>
            <label>Model</label>
            <input
              className='u-full-width'
              placeholder='Model'
              type='text'
              onChange={this.handleModelChanged}
              value={this.state.Model}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='six columns'>
            <label>Plate</label>
            <input
              className='u-full-width'
              placeholder='VPlateIN'
              type='text'
              onChange={this.handlePlateChanged}
              value={this.state.Plate}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='six columns'>
            <label>ODO</label>
            <input
              className='u-full-width'
              placeholder='ODO'
              type='text'
              onChange={this.handleODOChanged}
              value={this.state.ODO}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='six columns'>
            <label>Notes</label>
            <input
              className='u-full-width'
              placeholder='Notes'
              type='text'
              onChange={this.handleNotesChanged}
              value={this.state.VIN}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row'> 
        <div className="col-md-4">
        <button  onClick={this.addNew} variant="primary">Add a New Device</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: you are adding a string instead of an object `"{name: 'device 2', component: <StepThree/>},"`

Comment: I've been reading about objects but am still having trouble figuring out how to that new line to my steps array.

Comment: it should be `steps: [...previousState.steps, {name: 'device 2', component: <StepThree/>}]`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're trying to call `setState` inside `StepTwo` component but you don't store the steps in component's state there.

You're using a separate `.js` file to store the steps. This way React doesn't get notified when the steps array is changed and thus won't update (it will at some point, when it's re-rendered for some another reason, but you usually don't want that).

Looking at `react-multistep` docs, it seems that they don't provide a way to update steps array and don't allow you to pass additional props to form components.

I see two ways for you to fix the problem, considering you don't want to introduce a state management library like `redux` or `mobx`:
1. Use `React's Context API` to pass the state and update function to the form components
2. Create a fork of `react-multistep` to make it pass the props you pass to `MultiStep` component down to the form components - the library is pretty small (just 1 small component basically). This way you will be able to use component's state.

**Solution with Context API:**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import MultiStep from "react-multistep";
import { Route, NavLink, HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import newdevice from "./new-device";

export const StepsContext = React.createContext();

class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    steps: [
      { name: "Job", component: <StepOne /> },
      { name: "device 1", component: <StepTwo /> }
    ]
  };

  addStep = newStep => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      steps: [...prevState.steps, newStep]
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { steps } = this.state;

    return (
      <StepsContext.Provider value={{ steps, addStep: this.addStep }}>
        <div>
          <h1>Start a New Job</h1>

          <div className="container">
            <div>
              <MultiStep steps={steps} />
            </div>
            <div className="container app-footer">
              <h6>Press 'Enter' or click on progress bar for next step.</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </StepsContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Then, in your form components:

```js
import { StepsContext } from "./Home";

const AddStepComponent = () => (
  <StepsContext.Consumer>
    {({ addStep }) => (
      <button
        onClick={() => addStep({ name: "device 2", component: <StepThree /> })}
      >
        Add a new step
      </button>
    )}
  </StepsContext.Consumer>
);
```